# Combine computational graphs in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, We are currently working with the model that has three networks say **networkA**, **networkB** and **networkC**. The **networkB** and **networkC** are freezed.

The flow of the model is,

**input --> networkA --> outputA --> networkB --> outputB**
**input** and **outputB** --> **networkC** --> **Loss**

**Loss** will be used in backpropagation process to train **networkA**

The issue is **networkA** and **networkB** are in same graph and **networkC** is a different graph.

How to combine the graphs to **backpropagate** the **loss value** to update the gradients in **networkA**?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: There's several missing details in your question, please update your question with the following details: 1. Do `networkA`, `networkB` and `networkC` share any weights/variables? 2. Do you absolutely need to have two graphs or can you merge them if needed? 3. Please give some code that you've written, it will be helpful for us to answer.

Comment: The two graphs don't share any weights or variables. networkC is loaded from pb file in the session of networkA. Is it possible to load two graphs into the same session?
The only connection between the two graph is input and outputA from first graph is fed into the networkC as input. The output of networkC is fed into the networkA as loss value.